# Add item in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want to add item into the listview, the problem I'm facing is that when I add an item that I type in on the text box. It is able to insert the value in the listview column that I want. But when it update, all the data that it loaded from the textfile is missing. Only the value that I type in is left.

Before add data:
http://www.hostpic.org/images/1508121529460086.png

After insert the data:
http://www.hostpic.org/images/1508121531010086.png

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //add button
    string s;
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    listView1.BeginUpdate();

    for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if ((comboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1) + "" == proDetail[i].id)
        {
            //proDetail[i].estimation = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            proDetail[i].estimation = textBox3.Text;
            s = textBox4.Text;
            proDetail[i].pre = s.Split(',');
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < comboBox1.Items.Count; j++)
    {
        if (proDetail[j].pre != null)
        {
            project = listView1.Items.Add(proDetail[j].id);
            project.SubItems.Add(proDetail[j].activity);

            if (proDetail[j].pre.Length <= 1)
            {
                foreach (string words in proDetail[j].pre)
                {
                    preValue = words;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                preValue = string.Empty;
                foreach (string words in proDetail[j].pre)
                {
                    preValue += words + ",";
                }
            }
            project.SubItems.Add(proDetail[j].estimation.ToString());
            project.SubItems.Add(preValue);         
        }
        else
        {
            project = listView1.Items.Add(proDetail[j].id);
            project.SubItems.Add(proDetail[j].activity);
        }
        listView1.EndUpdate();
        listView1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you use? wpf, winform?

Comment: Obviously it's winforms, look on screens.

Comment: @israelaltar is windows form. sorry about forgot to list it down

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to include the 
project.SubItems.Add(proDetail[j].estimation);

in the else statement. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the culprit:

```
listView1.Items.Clear();
```

That has removed all existing items from the control.